# Having trouble with borders when ng-view content is larger than the window height

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the following to add border to my app:

```
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; }

body:before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    background: #124381;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 60px;
}

body:after {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    background: #124381;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 10px;
}
body:before {
    top: 0;
}
body:after {
    bottom: 0;
}
body   {
    border-left: 10px solid #124381;
    border-right: 10px solid #124381;  
}
```

However, if my ng-view is larger than the screen, and has a scroll, then when I scroll down, the borders disappears.

My html  is:

```
<body>
   <div id="app-views" class="container">
      <div ng-view=""></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

I have just one template loading right now, which consists of 3 500px high jumboton

When I use the google chrome to inspect, my body is showing as only 500px high, and the below 1000px is not having the border.

I tried various things, but I want the body to have border, and regardless of scroll or no scroll, I want the border to always be there.

I can get the scrolling border to work if I do the following.  However, then the non scroll breaks :(

To make scrolling work I can change to this:

`html, body { min-height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; }`

Is there a way to do this via css so works in all cases?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do.

You can add a border on each side of your `navbar` and remove the margin of 10px from each side.

Also should have body in this rule `html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; }` as this is actually interfering with the border and your after and before for the body should be together in a one rule.

See working example below at full page.

```css
/*Use this rule without BODY if it's needed*/
/*
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}*/
body:before,
body:after {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  background: #124381;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 10px;
}
body:before {
  top: 0;
}
body:after {
  bottom: 0;
}
body {
  border-left: 10px solid #124381;
  border-right: 10px solid #124381;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
.navbar.navbar-ng {
  background-color: #fff;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  border: none;
  border-left: 10px solid #124381;
  border-right: 10px solid #124381;
}
.navbar .navbar-brand.navbar-brand-centered {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
}
.navbar > .container .navbar-brand.navbar-brand-centered,
.navbar > .container-fluid .navbar-brand.navbar-brand-centered {
  margin-left: -100px;
}
/* Make the masthead heading the same height as the navigation */

.header h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 19px;
}
/* Custom page footer */

.footer {
  padding-top: 19px;
  color: #777;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.container-narrow > hr {
  margin: 30px 0;
}
/* Main marketing message and sign up button */

.jumbotron {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.jumbotron .btn {
  font-size: 21px;
  padding: 14px 24px;
}
/* Supporting marketing content */

.marketing {
  margin: 40px 0;
}
.marketing p + h4 {
  margin-top: 28px;
}
/* Responsive: Portrait tablets and up */

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 730px;
  }
  /* Remove the padding we set earlier */
  .header,
  .marketing,
  .footer {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  /* Space out the masthead */
  .header {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  /* Remove the bottom border on the jumbotron for visual effect */
  .jumbotron {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body ng-app="ramsiteApp">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-ng navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#js-navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

          </button>
        </div> <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered" href="#/">Ram M's Tea Man</a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><a href="#/">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a ng-href="#/services">Services</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a ng-href="#/about">About</a>

            </li>
            <li><a ng-href="#/contact">Contact</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="app-views" class="container">
    <div ng-view="">
      <div class="alert alert-info">YUP</div>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia,
      looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de
      Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from
      a line in section 1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney
      College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32
      and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit
      amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor
      at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes
      from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum,
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock,
      a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.
      Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line
      of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.
      Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the
      undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance.
      The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over
      2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature,
      discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular
      during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature
      from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word
      in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory
      of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical
      Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the
      cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise
      on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
      <div class="alert alert-danger">YUP</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```